# How to retrive differentiation results with Eigen::AutoDiffScalar

Tags: c++, eigen, autodiff

I am learning to use this library.  Trying to differentitate a simple function, `y = x^2`, does not yield the expected results (`dy/dx = 2x = 16` when `x = 8`).

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/AutoDiff>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Eigen::AutoDiffScalar<Eigen::Vector2d> x(8.0), y;

  y = x*x;

  std::cout << y.derivatives()[0];

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scalar you have declared is literally just that – a scalar, so you are finding the derivative of a scalar (8*8), which is 0.  To indicate that 8 is the value of the first variable, you need to set its first derivative to 1:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/AutoDiff>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Note different initialization
  Eigen::AutoDiffScalar<Eigen::Vector2d> x(8.0, Eigen::Vector2d(1,0)), y;

  y = x*x;

  std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n"
            << "y = " << y << "\n"
            << "y' = " << y.derivatives()[0] << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

This outputs

> x = 8
>   y = 64
>   y' = 16

I recommend naming the variable something other than `x`, because it can be easily confusing if you're expecting to take the derivative with respect to something that is usually called *x* as well.  So, let's call it `a` instead.

- If da/dx=0, then a is a constant.  Then, obviously, d/dx a² = 0 as well.
- if da/dx=1, then essentially a=x.  Then, d/dx a²  = d/dx x² = 2x.